# Meteor "cannot find module 'braintree'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, braintree

I'm trying to integrate Braintree payments with my site, but Meteor keeps giving the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'Braintree'
```

I added meteor to my project using both `meteor add ulexus:braintree` and `meteor add hiukim:braintree-helper`.

I followed along with [this](https://atmospherejs.com/hiukim/braintree-helper) to try and get my project working. Here's my code:

```
// inside Meteor.startup
Braintree = Npm.require('braintree');
var config = Braintree.connect({
  environment: Braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: "my merchant id",
  privateKey: "my private key",
  publicKey: "my public key"
});
BraintreeHelper.getInstance().connect(config);
```

I have also tried installing Braintree with `sudo npm install braintree` but that didn't work either. If I try without `Braintree = ...` I get the error `cannot call method baseUrl on undefined`.

I would really appreciate any help. Note: I have never used Braintree before and have only recently started using Meteor.

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either. However I know there is at least one Braintree developer using Meteor atm so hopefully they can help.

Comment: Alright, I eventually got it to work. Remove the lines `Braintree = Npm.require('braintree')` and `BraintreeHelper.getInstance().connect(config)`  (a bit odd considering the Atmospherejs readme said to have those in there) and then update the `packages.json` file to include `"hokum:braintree-helper" : "1.0.0"`

Comment: @Trent I work at Braintree. If that solved your problem, please post it as an answer so I can vote for it & others can find it more easily. Glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Same error here. Worked fine. Then I updated to Meteor 1.0.4 now the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add braintree with

```
npm install braintree
```

and use it with

```
var braintree = require("braintree");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with react project,

`npm install braintree` wasn't working.

If it's also not working in your case, then install it globally.

```
npm install -g braintree
```